# How do I change the profile image in Read The Docs?

Tags: website

How do I change the profile image associated with my account in [Read The Docs](https://readthedocs.org/)? I tried going to profile and Admin, but there doesn't seem to be any way to update the image associated with my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't actually find any documentation on it, but the profile picture seems to be taken from Gravatar, i.e. after changing my primary mail address on RTD to one that has a Gravatar picture, the picture appeared on my RTD profile.